# insert multiple rows in database of Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am new to CodeIgniter. I have got stuck up with a problem. I am developing a school management system, where I will have to display a page containing all the information of the students. There will be an additional checkbox to mark the students present or absent. On clicking the save button, the students present will have their data updated all together. Please I would request you all to send a  framework and base code of the controller model and view in CodeIgniter to help me understand how to work on it.

Comment: duplicate question
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14946766/codeigniter-insert-multiple-records-without-cycle

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please post any code you already have or what you tried. We will help you with specific problems but aren't the ones who write your code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `insert_batch` Active record function of CodeIgniter.

You can create array of data which you want to add and then pass it to `insert_batch` function.

[Codeigniter Documentation](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html#insert)

Comment: Please don't post urls in code tags (if they don't belong to the code) - the are not linked in code tags