# How can i insert multiple arrays into mysql database using codeginiter?

Tags: codeigniter

What i want is, i have a uniq id call **num** i want insert **mutiple description** for that unique **num**. i have a form to add fileds **dynamically** so i can add fields as much i want. when i try to insert one row data its works perfectly when i try to insert more than one row data it doesn't work.

**My View page :**

```
<form name="codexworld_frm" action="" method="post">

<div class="field_wrapper">
<input type="text" name="num" value=""/><br />

<input type="text" name="description[]" value=""/><input type="text" name="voucher_no[]" value=""/><input type="text" name="price[]" value=""/>
        <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="add_button" title="Add field"><img src="<?php echo base_url('images/add-icon.png'); ?>"/></a>

</div>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="SUBMIT"/>
</form>
```

**My Controller :**

```
$data = array(
                'no' => $this->input->post('num'),
                'descriptions' => $this->input->post('description'),
                'voucher' => $this->input->post('voucher_no'),
                'des_price' => $this->input->post('price'),
            );

            $this->multi_model->form_insert($data);

            $data['message'] = 'Data Inserted Successfully';
            //Loading View
            $this->load->view('multi_view', $data);
```

**My Model:**

```
function form_insert($data){

    $this->db->insert('tbl_description', $data);
    }
```

***if i use foreache loop into my model i think it will work but i how do i use ?***

**When i use print_r()** function this is out put

```
    1001
Array
    (
        [0] => description1
        [1] => description2
        [2] => description3
    )
    Array
    (
        [0] => voucher 1
        [1] => voucher 2
        [2] => voucher 3
    )
    Array
    (
        [0] => 100
        [1] => 200
        [2] => 300
    )
```

Comment: you can use `$this->db->insert_batch();`

Comment: that also dsnt work :(

Comment: you want to insert only description multi times or whole $data ?

Comment: **num** is  **id** for description so every descrption has **voucher_no** and **price**

Answer (score 6):

see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14946766/codeigniter-insert-multiple-records-without-cycle) link it is use multiple insert without loop or you can use your foreach loop in controller count description post and go through it.

```
    $data = array();

    $count = count($this->input->post['description']);

    for($i=0; $i < $count; $i++) {
        $data[] = array(
            'no'=>$this->input->post('num'),
            'descriptions' => $this->input->post['descriptions'][$i],
            'voucher' => $this->input->post['voucher'][$i],
            'des_price' => $this->input->post['des_price'][$i],
           );
    }
    $this->db->insert_batch('tbl_description', $data);
```

Comment: in this link only have two arrays ryt but i want add arrays dynamically it will b 1 or 2 or 3 or........etc

Comment: you can print_r($_POST['description']) and see the result array use for it in foreach loop and other post are same it is and you are done for multiple insert using foreach loop.

Answer (score 1):

Hope this will helps you..

Controller

```
//if voucher_no is required..

$voucher_no = $this->input->post('voucher_no');    
$count = count($voucher_no);
if ($count > 0) {
   for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {
       if (!empty($voucher_no[$i])) {
          $data = array(
            'no' => $this->input->post('num'),
            'descriptions' => $this->input->post('description')[$i],
            'voucher' => $this->input->post('voucher_no')[$i],
            'des_price' => $this->input->post('price')[$i],
            );

          $this->multi_model->form_insert($data);
        }
      } 
   }

 $data['message'] = 'Data Inserted Successfully';
 //Loading View
 $this->load->view('multi_view', $data);
```

Let us know the results..

Comment: **num** is my primary key every description has vocher_no and price

Answer (score 1):

change model as following.

```
function form_insert($data){
    foreach($data['description'] as $key=>$des)
    {
      $savedata = array(
            'no' => $data('no'),
            'descriptions' => $des,
            'voucher' => $data['voucher'][$key],
            'des_price' => $data['dec_price'][$key],
        );
      $this->db->insert('tbl_description', $savedata);
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
you can insert object wise.

in your controller:-

$value=$this->input->post('num');
$count=count($val);
for($i=0; $i<$count; $i++){

$data['no']=$this->input->post('num')[$i];
$data['description']=$this->input->post('description')[$i];
$data['voucher']=$this->input->post('voucher')[$i];
$data['prize']=$this->input->post('prize')[$i];

$this->multi_model->form_insert($data);
}
```