# batch insert prevent cyclic insert codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Hi I faced a problem when I insert some value from dynamic adding table then it insert with cycle.

But I want to insert all my arrays at once how it possible.

This is my Model:

```
$id=$this->input->post('id');
$rank=$this->input->post('rank');
$name=$this->input->post('name');
$mob=$this->input->post('mob');
$count = count($this->input->post('id'));

$data = array();

for($i=0, $i>$count; $i++) {

    $data[] = array(
    'id'=> null,
    'pers_no' => $id[$i],
    'rank' => $rank[$i],
    'name' => $name[$i],
    'mobile' => $mob[$i],
    'vendor_id' => $vendor[$i],
    );

    $result = $this->db->insert_batch('workers_tbl', $data);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$id=$this->input->post('id');
$rank=$this->input->post('rank');
$name=$this->input->post('name');
$mob=$this->input->post('mob');
$count = count($this->input->post('id'));

$data = array();

for($i=0, $i>$count; $i++) {

$data[] = array(
'id'=> null,
'pers_no' => $id[$i],
'rank' => $rank[$i],
'name' => $name[$i],
'mobile' => $mob[$i],
'vendor_id' => $vendor[$i],
);}

$result = $this->db->insert_batch('workers_tbl', $data);
```

Please try this may be work for you....

Put your insert_batch query outside the loop completed. i have only once change and remain same..

Answer (score 1):

You are inserting one record, this isn't called batch insertion. Just create an array and insert the record. In your model function

```
public function insert_record($data)
{
   $record=array(
     'pers_no' => $data['id'],
     'rank' => $data['rank'],
     'name' => $data['name'],
     'mobile' => $data['mobile'],
   );
   $this->db->insert('workers_tbl',$record);
}
```

You can secure your input by doing

```
$this->db->escape($data); // before creating the record array
```

From your controller just call this function once you store the post in some variable like

```
public function insert_worker()
{
   if($_POST)
   {
     $data=$this->input->post();
     $this->model_name->insert_record($data);
   }
}
```

if you want to create one huge array of multiple records . [Read this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14946766/codeigniter-insert-multiple-records-without-cycle/14946970)

Comment: create array of arrays, read the link of the thread I mentioned

Comment: if its a huge file like 5k+ records you might wanna set max_exec time in php.in or time_out . There are some default values which stops the server from long scripts executions

Answer (score 0):

```
$id=$this->input->post('id');
$rank=$this->input->post('rank');
$name=$this->input->post('name');
$mob=$this->input->post('mob');
$count = count($this->input->post('id'));

$data = array();

for($i=0, $i>$count; $i++) {

    $data[] = array(
    'pers_no' => $id[$i],
    'rank' => $rank[$i],
    'name' => $name[$i],
    'mobile' => $mob[$i],
    'vendor_id' => $vendor[$i],
    );


}
$result = $this->db->insert_batch('workers_tbl', $data);
```

Comment: Could you explain your answer? How does it solve the problem?

Answer (score -1):

Try this...

$count = $_POST['id'];

for($i=0, $i < $count; $i++){

```
$data[] = array(
    'pers_no' => $id[$i],
    'rank' => $rank[$i],
    'name' => $name[$i],
    'mobile' => $mob[$i],
    'vendor_id' => $vendor[$i]
```

);

}

$this->db->insert('workers_tbl',$data);

This may work.
Thanks.