# Codeigniter Can't Input All Data From Excel To Database

Tags: excel, database, codeigniter, insert, import-from-excel

i want to insert data imported from excel

i have 2 data entries but it inserts only one
this is my excel data 
[pictures](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9S5rW.png)
this is my code

```
      $objReader= PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader('Excel2007'); // For excel 2007     
      //Set to read only
      $objReader->setReadDataOnly(true);      
      //Load excel file
      $objPHPExcel=$objReader->load(FCPATH.'media/export_redeem/'.$file_name);    
      $allDataInSheet = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->toArray(null,true,true,true);        
      $arrayCount = count($allDataInSheet);
           for($i=2;$i<=$arrayCount;$i++)
            {
                $product_id= $allDataInSheet[$i]["A"];     
                $email= $allDataInSheet[$i]["B"]; //Excel Column 1
                $voucher= $allDataInSheet[$i]["C"]; //Excel Column 2

                $date=$allDataInSheet[$i]["D"]; //Excel Column 3
                $last = $this->db->where('member_email',$email)
                                ->get('member')
                                ->row('member_id');
                    $input=array(
                    'product_id'=>$product_id, 
                    'member_email'=>$email ,
                    'member_id'=>$last ,
                    'voucher_code'=>$voucher ,
                    'created_date'=>$date , 
                    'status'=>"1",
                    // 'created_date' =>date("Y-m-d H:i:s"),
                    'deleted' => "0"
                  );
                   $this->global_model->save_data($input,"redeem_product");
                  redirect("admin_redeem_transaction");

            }
```

this is my model

```
 function save_data($data, $table){
    $return = FALSE;
    if ($this->db->insert($table, $data)){
        $return = TRUE;
    }

    return $return;
}
```

please help, sorry for my english

Comment: You can use multi-row insert like: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14946766/codeigniter-insert-multiple-records-without-cycle

Comment: @AjeetKumar thank you so much

Comment: Is your problem resolved?

Comment: redirect("admin_redeem_transaction"); plz move the redirect code out of for loop otherwise only one record will be inserted into DB.

Comment: @AjeetKumar yes its works now. thank you so much

Comment: @438sunil yes im forget about that. thank you